# This is only returning the largest letter word, when I want it to return the count for every letter word

Tags: java

I need to get this code to take the user input and tell me how many one-letter words, two-letter words, three-letter words, etc. there are. This code compiles, but it only gives me the number of times the word with the most letters is used. For example, if the user input were "I want to know why this is not working" The output would be one seven-letter word. It doesn't tell me how many times all the other number of letter words are used.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Analysis B { //open class

  public static String input;
  public static String stringB;

  public static void main (String args []) { //open main 


    System.out.println("Please enter a line of text for analysis:");

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    input = sc.nextLine();
    input = input.toLowerCase();



    System.out.println("Analysis B:");//Analysis B 
    System.out.println("Word length: " + "           Frequency: ");
    System.out.println(AnalysisB(stringB)); 




  } // close main 




    public static String AnalysisB (String stringB) { // open analysis B

       String [] words = input.split(" ");

       int largest = 0;

       for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) { //open for
          largest = Math.max( words[i].length(), largest); // get the largest   value 
       } //close for

       int [] frequencies = new int[ largest + 1 ]; 

       for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) { //open for
         frequencies[words[i].length()]++; 
       } //close for

       for (int i = 0; i < frequencies.length; i++) { //open for
         if (frequencies[i] > 0 ) { //open if
         stringB =(i + "-letter words" + "               " + frequencies[i]); 
         } //close if 
       } //close for

   return stringB;

  } // close analysis B





} //close class
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem:

```
stringB =(i + "-letter words" + "               " + frequencies[i]);
```

Each time this line of code is run, it assigns a new value to `stringB`, over-writing the previous value. Instead, you want it to look like this:

```
stringB += (i + "-letter words" + "               " + frequencies[i] + "\n");
```

The `+=` operator will add to `stringB` instead of replacing it (and the `"\n"` will ensure it adds to a new line each time).

By the way, there's no need to import `java.io.*`, since it isn't used in your program. `java.io` deals with file operations.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do this with a sorted HashMap (TreeMap):

```
public static void AnalysisB (String input)
{
    String [] words = input.split(" ");

    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();

    for (String w : words)
    {
        int len = w.length();

        Integer freq = map.get(len);
        if (freq == null)
        {
            map.put(len, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            map.put(len, freq + 1);
        }
    }

    for (Iterator<Integer> iter = map.keySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); )
    {
        int len = iter.next();
        System.out.println(len + "-letter words" + "             " + map.get(len));
    }
}
```

**Note**: I made the method void since you are just printing out the frequencies in the method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static String AnalysisB (String stringB) {
    return Stream.of(stringB.split(" "))
        .map(s -> s.length())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(n -> n, Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getKey()))
        .map(e -> e.getKey() + "-letter words         " + e.getValue())
        .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
}
```

and

```
System.out.println(AnalysisB("I want to know why this is not working"));
```

result:

```
1-letter words         1
2-letter words         2
3-letter words         2
4-letter words         3
7-letter words         1
```